# What triggers “Your startup disk is almost full.” message?

Tags: macos, startup, disk-space

[image]

You've probably seen this message (maybe in a bit newer GUI but still the same).

I wonder if anyone know when it is triggered?

Comment: I wonder how this is too broad @bmike? It is a question of how many MBs left or maybe percentage of the disk which is definite.

Comment: I would say - either ask when? or what? or possible? - it looks like three questions at a minimum to me. Maybe delete the entire last paragraph if the main point is to know when.

Comment: Although I can't find anything to prove this, I recall from the OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard days that the trigger was reaching 2GB or less free on the startup volume.